Unable to edit and capture Super Linter error into GitHub Issue
I am using Superlinter actions in GitHub Actions for code linting. I would like to trigger action once issue is created, and capture error that is raised by SQLFluff (Linter in SuperLiner) into the issue that was raised by the user. Currently, my main workflow file looks like below. However, for some reason I am unable to capture the error that is raised by linter into the issue.  What am I missing?
Main.yml (Updated code after jonrsharpe  comment)
name: close-issue-after-lint-open
on:
  issues:
    types: [opened]
jobs:
  close-issue:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      issues: write
      contents: read
      packages: read
      statuses: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.2.2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Super-linter
        uses: super-linter/super-linter@v7.2.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          VALIDATE_SQLFLUFF: true
          ENABLE_GITHUB_ACTIONS_STEP_SUMMARY: true
          SAVE_SUPER_LINTER_OUTPUT: true

      - name: Log-error-to-the-issue
        if: failure()
        env: 
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          ISSUE: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
          ERROR_LOG_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}
        run: 
          gh run view --log "$ERROR_LOG_PATH/error/super-linter"
      
          
      - name: Close
        env: 
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
          ISSUE: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        run:
          gh issue close --repo "$REPO" --comment "Autoclosing issue $ISSUE"
          "$ISSUE"


The "run" where you try to do that is an environment variable (and a step by definition cannot have both run and uses).

@jonrsharpe..thank you pointing the error. Fixed it. Now I am struggling to get/view the error logs using cli. Super Linter docu. mentions "If you set SAVE_SUPER_LINTER_OUTPUT to true, Super-linter saves its output to ${DEFAULT_WORKSPACE}/${SUPER_LINTER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME}/super-linter, so you can further process it, if needed" [https://github.com/marketplace/actions/super-linter]. How to go about adding error to Issue. I can run "gh issue edit "$ISSUE" --body "$ERROR_LOG_PATH", which will capture the path, but I need actual error and not path of where logs are located. Thanks in advance!

"I need actual error and not path of where logs are located" - so look up how to get the file content, given the path, in the shell (bash) you're using. Or look at the command you're using to see if it will do the equivalent, take the path to read rather than the content. There's no reason to expect --body "$ERROR_LOG_PATH" to do anything other than give the path itself.

For Future Stackoverflow reader,
Below is the code I use to resolve my issue. First, I wanted to see what are all the files I have? After that ,I narrowed down to the path I wanted and was able to add the JSON to the issue. Note, I added entire JSON to the issue, but was able to capture what I was looking for. Thanks @jonrsharpe for pointers.
name: close-issue-after-lint-open

on:
  issues:
    types: [opened]

jobs:
  close-issue:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      issues: write
      contents: read
      packages: read
      statuses: write
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.2.2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Run Super-linter
        uses: super-linter/super-linter@v7.2.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          VALIDATE_SQLFLUFF: true
          ENABLE_GITHUB_ACTIONS_STEP_SUMMARY: true
          
          
      - name: Log error to the issue
        if: failure()
        env: 
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          ISSUE: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
          ERROR_LOG_PATH: ${{ github.workspace }}/super-linter-output/super-linter/super-linter-worker-results-SQLFLUFF.json
        run: |
          echo "Listing all files and directories in workspace:"
          ls -R $GITHUB_WORKSPACE  # List everything recursively in the workspace
          
          # Optionally, list the contents of the specific super-linter output directory
          if [ -d "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/${{ env.SUPER_LINTER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME }}/super-linter" ]; then
            echo "Listing contents of the Super Linter output directory:"
            ls -R "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/${{ env.SUPER_LINTER_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME }}/super-linter"
          else
            echo "Super Linter output directory not found."
          fi
          
          # Check if the error log exists
          if [ -f "$ERROR_LOG_PATH" ]; then
            ERROR_LOG=$(cat "$ERROR_LOG_PATH")
          else
            ERROR_LOG="No errors found."
          fi

          # Post the error log to the issue
          gh issue comment $ISSUE --body "Super Linter found the following issues:$ERROR_LOG"

      - name: Close issue
        env: 
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          REPO: ${{ github.repository }}
          ISSUE: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
        run: |
          # Close the issue and add a comment
          gh issue close --repo "$REPO" --comment "Autoclosing issue $ISSUE due to linting errors."

